# How to stop InteliJ IDEA to highlight the identifier under the caret

Tags: intellij-idea

While typing with IntelliJ IDEA the identifier under the caret is highlight with a very ugly turquoise background. And all occurrences of identifier in a different shade of turquoise.

This can be helpfully. But not with that obtrusively ugly colour. And not right while I type.

Is there any way to configure that pain to become useful? A different colour might be nice. Or 2 sec delay. Perfect would be both.

Or if this is not possible then I rather live without and would like to know how to switch it of completely.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Settings | Editor | Highlight usages of element at caret (but it's disabled by default).

There is also Identifier Highlighter third-party plug-in which does almost the same.

Comment: Thanks. I made the mistake to install that third-party Highlighter. de-activated it and all was well again.

Answer (score 4):

@Martin I believe you can change this. If you go to settings -> general -> colours and fonts and find "Identifier under caret" you can customize things there!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I found that already. And changing does not help. But you got me thinking it might be a plug-in. I'll have a look.

Comment: This was my problem. For some reason the theme I had (my own, so my mistake) lacked proper coloring of `"Identifier under caret"`, so it wasn't visible for me. Thanks man!